# How can I display "Woocommerce Recently Viewed Products" horizontally just above the footer?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I’m using avada for theme. I don’t use extra plugin for recently viewed products.

I want to add “recently viewed products” -that inclueded to woocommerce option as a shortcode to the page. Like examples on this page: docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes For example I can add “order tracking” option to page with this code. [woocommerce_order_tracking] How do I add the widget to appear on all page just before the footer area? How do I make that widget horizontal instead of vertical? Are there any shortcodes for adding “recently viewed products” option?

Please do not propose 3rd party plugins.*
[image]

Comment: This highly depends on the theme you are using. You can copy the php code that shows the recently viewed products and paste it before the footer file. We can't help directly since we don't have the theme.

Comment: Have you got a link to the recently viewed products plugin you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way. For those who need:

```
 /**
 * @snippet       [recently_viewed_products] Shortcode - WooCommerce
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 3.6.2
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */
 
add_shortcode( 'recently_viewed_products', 'bbloomer_recently_viewed_shortcode' );
 
function bbloomer_recently_viewed_shortcode() {
 
   $viewed_products = ! empty( $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'] ) ? (array) explode( '|', wp_unslash( $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'] ) ) : array();
   $viewed_products = array_slice($viewed_products, 0, 8);

 
   if ( empty( $viewed_products ) ) return;
    
   $title = '<h3 class="product-section-title container-width product-section-title-related pt-half pb-half uppercase">Du tittade senast på</h3>';
   $product_ids = implode( ",", $viewed_products );
 
   return $title . do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids']");
   
}

// adds notice at single product page above add to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'recviproducts', 31 );
function recviproducts() {
    echo do_shortcode ('[recently_viewed_products]');
}

// https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/9724#issuecomment-160618200
function custom_track_product_view() {
    if ( ! is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    global $post;

    if ( empty( $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'] ) )
        $viewed_products = array();
    else
        $viewed_products = (array) explode( '|', $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'] );

    if ( ! in_array( $post->ID, $viewed_products ) ) {
        $viewed_products[] = $post->ID;
    }

    if ( sizeof( $viewed_products ) > 15 ) {
        array_shift( $viewed_products );
    }

    // Store for session only
    wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_recently_viewed', implode( '|', $viewed_products ) );
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_track_product_view', 20 );
```